# Can't open Microsoft Access database

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a Microsoft Access database and I'm trying to open it.
When I do, I get "Unknown User Does Not Have Permission".
Is there any way to open this file?
I'm using Microsoft Access 2007 under Windows XP.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the extension of the "database"? Is it .mde/.accde, or .mdb/.accdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the database has a permissions file attached to it, and your login is not a part of the group that has permissions.

The easiest way is to ask the original developer for the user name and pwd that you can use to log into the database.

Comment: I don't know who exactly created this file, but I don't even see a way to log in as a user. Where do I enter username and password?

Answer (score 1):

Please post a screenshot so we can know the exact error.

If this is on entry, it is probably Microsoft DRM either protecting it over the network to a server in your company or over the Internet to the public Office DRM Server.

If it is protected by this, then I am not really sure we should help you to get around it - and not 100% sure you can.

If it isn't this, again, please post a screenshot so we can know exactly and I can try to help you further.

Comment: What leads you to think it's DRM and not simply Jet user-level security, or a database password?

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a blank database, then use the link tables tables option to access the table. There might be a table called users where you can insert your login name. Then open the database directly and see if you can bypass the "Unknown User Does Not Have Permission" prompt.

If know a user that has access to the database, you can also try [RunAs](http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html) to impersonate a user that is on the access list.

Answer (score -1):

If you are opening a *.MDB file, Access used a security scheme defined in a local MS Access system database named *.MDW - there is a default installed with MS Access, but one can also create one's own.  You will need to know a valid user ID and password from that database to open it.

If you are opening the more recent *.ACCDB format, Access sticks to file system security.  Either the filesystem does not authorize you to access it, or there is logic within the database that is checking on you (Access can tell your network ID, for example) and displaying that message through application code.